# Train images classifier not working on orthomosaic GeoTIFF file

Tags: qgis, gdal, image-classification, orfeo-toolbox

When I run the train images classifier on an orthomosaic or orthophoto by OTB in QGIS it generates me not just a file with .txt extension but by default it starts generating .txt.shp, .txt.shx, .txt.dbf, .txt.xml etc. I am unable to resolve this issue, is my orthophoto too big or could it be its reading the data in a wrong way? The orthophoto is of high resolution.

Comment: Those file endings look like it's producing a shapefile. Was there specific documentation that led you to understand it would produce a text file instead?

Comment: Could you tell us which otb application is used ?